# What's reverted and not reverted during an Out of Gas exception?

Tags: security, out-of-gas, consensus, exceptions, precompiled-contracts

A seemingly crucial question on [EIP 158 was unanswered](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/158#issuecomment-255537140):

> Unless the empty accounts are deleted even in the case of an EVM
>   exception, if that is the case would that not break the guarantee that
>   EVM exceptions revert the state back as if the transaction was never
>   made?

It seems this lead to the [Nov 24 consensus security alert](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/25/security-alert-11242016-consensus-bug-geth-v1-4-19-v1-5-2)?

When a transaction encounters an Out of Gas (OOG) exception, some changes are reverted and some are not.  For example, contract storage changes are reverted, whereas the transaction itself is not reverted (it remains on the blockchain and the gas payment to the miner is made).  If the transaction deleting empty accounts runs OOG, the empty accounts should be brought back except for a ["set of contexts involving out-of-gas calls to precompiled contracts"](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/25/security-alert-11242016-consensus-bug-geth-v1-4-19-v1-5-2).

1. What specifically are these contexts? Can [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3341/files#r89548318) be explained?
2. What is the clear, complete list of conditions/changes that are reverted and not reverted during an Out of Gas exception?